# How to type a dictionary made from an object in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Quite often I use objects as dictionaries e.g.

```js
type Foo = { a: string }

type MyDictionary = { [key: string]: Foo }

function foo(dict: MyDictionary) {
  // Requirement 1: Should be of type Foo[]
  const values = Object.values(dict)

  // Requirement 2: Should be of type Foo | undefined
  const aValue = dict.b

  // Requirement 3: Should fail
  dict.c = undefined
}
```

#### Workaround 1

My default choice is

```js
type MyDictionary = Record<string, Foo> // aka { [key: string]: Foo }
```

This will pass 1 and 3 but fail on 2.

#### Workaround 2

```js
{ [key: string]: Foo | undefined }
```

This will pass 2 but fail on 1 & 3.

#### Workaround 3

Another option is to stick with option 1 but use a getter function to keep things safer

```js
export function safeGet<T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): T[K] | undefined {
  return obj[key]
}

safeGet(dict, 'b')
```

Any other suggestions?

Note: I know `Map` does this well, but using `Map` is not always a practical refactor. This question is specifically for objects as dictionaries.

Comment: It seems that you're looking for [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgDnbN).  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz looking forward to your answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the functionality provided by [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess), which adds `undefined` to the domain of the type you get when *reading* a property covered by an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), without also doing so to the type you're allowed to *write* to the same property.  And note that it doesn't affect the return type of [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values), whose [declaration](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/f473058361474507b03726b1ac9cd280c9580091/src/lib/es2017.object.d.ts#L6) is

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
  values<T>(o: { [s: string]: T } | ArrayLike<T>): T[];
}
```

---

Note that this compiler option is *not* part of [the `--strict` suite of compiler options](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict), and is therefore not considered a "standard" type safety option.  That's because, while it is sometimes desirable to guard against `undefined` this way, it can be *quite annoying* in other circumstances, by generating errors in very common idiomatic JavaScript.

For example, [array types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#arrays) in TypeScript have a `number` index signature.  Enabling `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` gets in the way of the very common use case of iterating through an array by looping through its numeric indices:

```
const arr = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i].toUpperCase()); // error!
    // -------> ~~~~~~ Object is possibly undefined
}
```

Technically, sparse arrays exist, so one could argue that this error *should* happen... but in practice it is often more trouble than it's worth to have the compiler do such checks.

So if you want this check, you'll need to enable it explicitly.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBDAXFAzsAJwEsA7AcygF8Aoa0SKAWRABEiBjYIuEjAkZGigBtANYQQOfMXIBdHPEQ1qAMwCuJTtxJQVCABQATDsBzM2WnnxABKNNSiOoAemdQAShACOaogQgAthAkwFAAjDgAygAWcGoANoZQAEbQcCpQ9NCKwrIOTuw8+FAAbhjxahC4ggDyyQBWEJwAdGUVVUYmNrROLm6ePn6BwaEATFGxCUmpUOmZ4NkIUAA+UBqGECqkEIb5joUkxRgAauWVgsYtyT1Orh7evv5BIVAAzBNxiboYRPF7UJdgM12IJ1pttrtlAcjgQCIJhAAiDAIgA0UARyVR6PYWIRhlxEARsgA3Ko4HD9PEIKEiIIAAzEqC0gA8mFhzSp5GA0UZRAA1Hy7Kh-tC4FSOXAyPo+ARhERZM1gHAAKpgSAEADCGFwEH0NhsjLuEFh5IAhP87gBaa02y0APigAD9nS6oHVGpwmdUwHBcLgiMl4gIwVsSDtqJQgA)

Comment: You can use `for (const [i, item] of arr.entries())` for your annoying case

Answer (score 1):

The API you're looking for is provided by [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).

```
type Foo = { a: string }

type MyDictionary = Map<string, Foo>();

function foo(dict: MyDictionary) {
  // Requirement 1: Should be of type Foo[]
  const values = [...dict.values()]

  // Requirement 2: Should be of type Foo | undefined
  const aValue = dict.get("b")

  // Requirement 3: Should fail
  dict.set("c", undefined)
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nKBeKBvKBDAXFAzsAJwEsA7AcygF8Aoa0SKAWRABEiBjYIuEjAkZEwxgAPPmLkANLAQA+ABQBKANy0AZgFcSnbiShqE8gCYdgOZmx08+IRWmpQoAeidQAShACOGogQgBbCBJgKABGHABlAAs4DQAbIygAI2g4NSh6aHg4AG0AXQcodh58KAA3DDiNCFxBHIA6RpNOeoqqmqUCwpd3Lx8-QOCoACZImPjElKg0jPAshCgAHygtIwg1UggjQuKSUowANUrqwWbgerIIYHkAIiSbxVpHHo9vXwCgkIBmMdiE-QwRDihTO9VwV1u7Bu0lW602RkeNCAA)

Comment: You are definitely right, Map is perfect but I often just use objects throughout the codebase.

Comment: @david_adler You _probably_ shouldn't. Using plain objects as dictionaries is unsound in TS and has a worse performance profile than Map. There is pretty much no reason to avoid Map.

Comment: Using objects as dictionaries is incredibly common though! Sometimes it's a third party or legacy code